# How to set default value to 0 on column database with liquibase?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, liquibase

I am working with liquibase. I have a User table with a column defined as follow :

```
<column name="referralClicks" type="int"/>
```

When i save my user for the first time in database. The referralClicks is null. But i want to set a default value (0) and i tried the following configuration :

```
 <addDefaultValue 
            columnDataType="int"
            columnName="referralClicks"
            defaultValueNumeric="0"
            tableName="USER"/>
   </changeSet>
```

I Use MySQL database. In the structure, i can see that the default value is set to 0.
[image]

But when i have data the referralClicks is null : 
[image]

In code also i retrieve null value when this is not set.

```
Integer referralClicks = user.getReferralClicks();
```

What am i missing ?

Comment: try with attribute _defaultValueNumeric_ in a column tag

Answer (score 3):

You can [`<update>`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/update.html) you existing data using  like this:

```
<update tableName="USER">
    <column name="referralClicks" valueNumeric="0"/>
    <where>referralClicks IS NULL</where>
</update>
```

or as already stated with raw [`<sql>`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html):

```
<sql>
    UPDATE USER SET referralClicks = 0 WHERE referralClicks IS NULL
</sql>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add a constraint for the column which you dont want to be null like below:

```
        <column name="columnName" type="int" defaultValueNumeric="0">
           <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you alter a column in a database to set a default value, that does NOT update existing rows in the database. You would have to write some sort of update script to update existing null values. Something like this:

```
UPDATE user 
 SET referralClicks = 0
WHERE referralClicks IS NULL
```

Comment: You're right but i execute the my liquibase on new database. When a user register an account the default value is always NULL.

Comment: I would use the mysql admin tools to look at the database then and see if the default value has been applied correctly or not. If so, the problem is with MySQL or perhaps your client code. If not, then the problem might be with Liquibase not applying the change correctly, or user error running Liquibase.

Comment: @Pracede there is a [`<sql>`](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html) in liquibase

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value like this for any data type (int, enum, etc.).

```xml
<!--ini-->
<column name="referral_clicks" type="INT DEFAULT 0">
  <constraints nullable="false"/>
</column>

<!--enum-->
<column name="my_type" type="ENUM('TYPE_1','TYPE_2') DEFAULT 'TYPE_1'">
  <constraints nullable="false"/>
</column>
```